# Java sorting an array of words with threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting

I have a txt-file of names I need to be able to sort alphabetically. My program then takes the array, splits into the amount of threads passed as an argument in the terminal, and gives each thread a piece of the array to sort, then stores all the threads in an array. Now, what I need some help with is this:
I now want to take threads, as soon as they are done (Ie. if two are done before the others, they start to merge then wait for more). Think of it like braiding. I know how to write the sorting code for the merging, but what I hope you can help me with is this: How do I manage the threads? I know what wait() and notify() does, but I can't seem to be able to wrap my ead around what exactly I would need to do to make them merge into one array. Should I:

1. Create a method inside the thread-class that merges the arrays?
2. Create a new thread for every other thread that is done, pass the two sorted word-arrays as a parameter, and let that thread do the sorting?
3. Something else I haven't thought of.

I hope this was clear enough, and of good enough quality as the questions should be.

Comment: I think the first option will be the best one, if you know how to do it.

Comment: @explodingcreeperssss OP's question is how to do it,

Comment: Oh. Well, I've never done threading, so that's why I didn't use the answer box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm and base its implementation on [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) (if you're using Java 7, of course).

This algorithm fits perfectly because the job can be splitted to independent tasks can be handled by different threads. Now, `ForkJoinPool` provides you with easy-to-use pool where you can submit your sorting tasks.

The implementation should be done like this:

- Each task does sorting a piece of array/list given;
- If the array is small (exact meaning of *small* can be configured by constant) - it is sorted using standard `.sort()` method, otherwise it is split in two halves and these halves are submitted to the pool for sorting;
- Then the task waits for both child tasks to complete and performs merging of two sorted arrays/lists into one, and returns it;

Here is the sample implementation of the algorithm. Please be aware that this one is far away from optimal as it consumes tons of additional memory. I implemented it like that to demostrate **approach**. Run it with `-Xmx1024m`.

```
public class ForkJoinSort {

    private static final int LIST_SIZE = 10000;

    private static final int SORT_THRESHOLD = 10; //the minimal length of the list to use standard java sort rather than mergesort

    private static ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();

    public static class MergeSortTask extends RecursiveTask<List<Integer>> {

        private final List<Integer> victim;

        public MergeSortTask(List<Integer> victim) {
            this.victim = victim;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Integer> compute() {
            if (victim.size() < SORT_THRESHOLD) {
                Collections.sort(victim);
                return victim;
            }

            //sorting left and right parts of the list separately in separate threads
            MergeSortTask leftTask = new MergeSortTask(victim.subList(0, victim.size() / 2));
            MergeSortTask rightTask = new MergeSortTask(victim.subList(victim.size() / 2, victim.size()));
            forkJoinPool.submit(leftTask);
            forkJoinPool.submit(rightTask);

            //do merge
            return merge(leftTask.join(), rightTask.join());
        }

        public List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {
            List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(left.size() + right.size());

            Iterator<Integer> leftIterator = left.iterator();
            Iterator<Integer> rightIterator = right.iterator();

            Integer fromLeft = null;
            Integer fromRight = null;

            while (leftIterator.hasNext() || rightIterator.hasNext()) {
                //if current value taken from the iterator is null - take new one if possible, otherwise do nothing
                fromLeft = fromLeft == null ? leftIterator.hasNext() ? leftIterator.next() : null : fromLeft;
                fromRight = fromRight == null ? rightIterator.hasNext() ? rightIterator.next() : null : fromRight;

                if (fromLeft != null && (fromRight == null || fromLeft <= fromRight)) {
                    result.add(fromLeft);
                    fromLeft = null; //this is done to indicate that value from left iterator already passed to result list
                } else if (fromRight != null && (fromLeft == null || fromRight <= fromLeft)) {
                    result.add(fromRight);
                    fromRight = null;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        //generate array of random numbers
        List<Integer> victim = new ArrayList<Integer>(LIST_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; ++i) {
            victim.add(random.nextInt());
        }

        //do some benchmarking as long as we're here
        long timeMark = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSortTask task = new MergeSortTask(victim);
        forkJoinPool.submit(task);
        List<Integer> probablySorted = task.get();
        timeMark = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMark;

        //asserting that array is sorted
        for (int i = 0; i < probablySorted.size() - 1; ++i) {
            if (probablySorted.get(i) > probablySorted.get(i + 1)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Sorting failed :(");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sorting " + LIST_SIZE + " random numbers using merge sort algorithm in " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + " threads took " + timeMark + " ms.");
    }
}
```

I tried to make code easy-readable. If I failed somewhere, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Your answer is clearer than mine, Rather than cleaning up mine I'll just upvote yours :)

Comment: @durron597 Thanks for fairness :) Although for me it would be just fine to have two answers for this question.

Comment: Sure except mine didn't add anything yours didn't already say :-D

Comment: The interesting part is *merging* in parallel. Without a parallel merge you get only O(lg n) parallelism (still work efficient though) which is practically irrelevant. You can get at least O(n / lg^2 n) parallelism with a parallel merge which *does* make a big difference. The really interesting part is doing that without an auxiliary array in-place, not sure what the best known result for that one actually is and don't have my copy of CLRS around to look it up..

Comment: If it isn't too much hassle, I would love to see a an implementation of this. I am not too confident in my skills in this, but I will look into it as well! 
EDIT: As written, I have already done the initial sorting, and now I need to merge two and two threads, using braiding. (If that is the correct word, I am not a native speaker of english) the problem is how to manage the threads and make them respond to each other and start merging. If ForkJoinPool can do this, I will be very happy. Looking into it now.

Comment: @Voo I think both OP, me and many other users on SO would be glad to see merge sort with parallel merge too. Maybe you can post an example too?

Comment: @user3618545 Sure. But I need maybe an hour or two to get to the office when I'll be able to use IDE. If that's ok, I'll post the code in a few hours.

Comment: @Alexey With an auxiliary array the code is simple enough that I could definitely do that - as long as pseudo code is fine, not such a big fan of Java in my free time :-)

Comment: I can add the code I have so far in my original post, if you'd like. Then you can use that. I have only made it take in a number of threads it shall start from terminal, create the arrays from textfile, and sort them. That is, I have tested the sorting algorithm by using a single thread for now, but I must be able to use atleast... 1000 I think is good. I want to measure the speed increases, you see. But for that I must be able to merge the arrays as soon as a thread is done sorting them

Comment: @Voo Yep, just fine for me.

Comment: @Alexey Comments always welcome, can't say Sunday at 3am in the morning is the best time to summarize algorithms or write pseudo code, but hey I think it's understandable ;)

Comment: @Voo Yes, same thing for me. I think I'll enter guru meditation state as soon as finish with the basic example for the OP :)

Comment: @user3618545 I have added the implementation as you asked.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Easily understandable as well :D Thanks alot.
One final question though; if I were to employ this implementation with n number of threads, initiated after reading in file and started separately in a for-loop, would I then just add a line with forkJoinPool.join(sorter) to the for-loop which creates them, so that every object is added to the pool right after they are done with the sorting, and then at the end merge them, two by two, until none remains?

Comment: Or do I create a new ForkJoinPool-object, and lob two and two sorted arrays, which I store in a list after they are sorted by their respective sorter-objects in separate threads, into the pool and let it mergesort them?

Comment: @Makri If you're going to use `ForkJoinPool`, you shouldn't start threads by yourself. Just set wanted parallelizm level in `ForkJoinPool` constructor instead.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess that I should use ForkJoinPool just after I have sorted the arrays initially, to merge the arrays, then? Since now I read the entire textfile, create an array out of it, splits into the number of parts indicated by number of threads given as an argument, start a new thread which sorts it's own part of the array using insertion sort. I don't know if ForkJoinPool will be possible to use instead?

Comment: @Makri Technically yes. You may pass "sort this part of array" tasks to pool, but you'll somehow need to wait for completion for at least pairs of them to do further merge, then pairs of upper level to merge again, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexey correctly points out the easiest way to do a parallel sort is definitely using a fork/join framework and merge sort. That's very easy to do and looks something like (pseudo code):

```
def mergesort(a, i0, i1):
    if i0 == i1:
        return
    im = i0 + (i1 - i0) / 2
    fork mergesort(a, i0, im)
    fork mergesort(a, im, i1)
    join
    merge(a, i0, im, i1) # serial merge
```

If we analyse this we see that we have (easy to show by master theorem):

```
Work: T_1(n) = 2T_1(n / 2) + O(n) = O(n lg n)
Span: T_inf(n) = 1 T_inf(n / 2) + O(n) = O(n)
```

where work means the total amount of work done and span describes how long it'd take if we had infinitely many threads available (basically the depth of the tree).

The parallelism an algorithm has is basically Work / Span which in this case gives us `O(lg n)` - that's practically irrelevant although if we use a good serial sort algorithm for small enough leaf sizes this still works quite well.

We can do better though by parallelizing the merge. This *can* be done without an auxiliary array, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader (means: not easy and I'd have to look up how to actually do that).

Parallel merge: Assume that we have an auxiliary array aux with two sorted arrays in [i0, i1) and [j0, j1) and we want to put the merged sub arrays into array a between k0, k1. We do this recursively again:

1. Compute im = i0 + (i1 - i0) / 2 - aux[im] is the median of the left half
2. Find jm so that aux[im] is inserted directly before aux[jm]
3. insert aux[im] into the correct position in a, which we know if we have im and jm.
4. merge the two subarrays.

Confused? Well, the following illustration (I'm in CS not arts..) should help I hope:[image: Helpful illustration]

In code this looks something like

```
def merge(a, aux, i0, i1, j0, j1, k0, k1):
    if i0 == i1:
        copy aux[j0, j1] to a[k0, k1]
        return
    if j0 == j1:
        copy aux[i0, i1] to a[k0, k1]
        return       
    im = im = i0 + (i1 - i0) / 2 
    jm = find(aux, j0, j1, aux[im]) 
    km = k0 + (im - i0) + 1 + (jm - j0 )
    a[km] = aux[im]
    fork merge(a, aux, i0, im, j0, jm, k0, km)
    fork merge(a, aux, im + 1, i1, jm, j1, km + 1, k1)
    join
```

It's important to note that `find` has to be done using a simple serial binary search in O(lg n)  since we know the right side is sorted.

Using such a parallel merge gives us the same work, but reduces the span to O(lg^3 n), which translates to a parallelism of O(n / lg^2 n) - which is a great improvement.

Nota bene: As for any parallel algorithm in practice you will want to use a simple serial version if the problem sizes get too small (quicksort or something) - which leaf size is the best has to be evaluated for each architecture separately through experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

I am a teaching assistant (and examiner for the assignment in question) for the university course you're following. The answers you've been given to your question(s) are great, and probably describe THE best ways to solve this problem for optimal performance and speed-up compared to a fully sequential sort+merge. You should keep in mind, though, that this is a beginner's course in object oriented programming, and your very first assignment touching parallelism and multithreading.

As there are only 14 hours left until the deadline, I would not recommend you to go for an advanced approach to the problem, like extending library classes such as ForkJoinPool, parallelising a double-pivot quicksort, or whatnot. The simplest solution to this problem, which is also the solution we had in mind when we gave you the assignment, can be implemented following these steps:

***Algorithm:***

n = number of threads

1. Read the words into a primitive String array from the file.
2. Split the array into *n* approximately equally long pieces, or alternatively, create a function which assigns indexes in the initial array to your threads.
3. Create the threads, giving them a reference ("Java pointer") to your monitor object.
4. Once the threads have been assigned parts of your initial array, start sorting them using whatever algorithm you would like. Insertion sort is probably the "easiest" algorithm to implement if you're short on time.
5. Once sorting is finished in a certain thread, have the thread report back to the monitor, letting it know sorting has been finished.
6. When two threads have reported back, have one of the threads perform an initially-sorted merge sort (description further down) on the arrays sorted by the threads.
7. Write the result back to a new file on your system

***"Initially-sorted merge sort"***

1. Create two ints, i and j, and let them represent indexes in the two initially sorted arrays.
2. Create an array as long as the two arrays' lengths added together.
3. Iterate from 0 through result.length, and check whether array1[i] is smaller than array2[j].
   3.1 If it is, add array1[i] to your result array, and increment i.
   3.2 If it is not, add array2[j] to your result array, and increment j.
4. Once you've reached the end of either initial array, simply add the rest of the other array to the result array.
5. At the end of the for-loop, your result array is sorted, and all the strings from array1 and array2 are contained in your result array.

Good luck with your assignment!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. What I'm mainly stuck at now is how do I get the sorter-threads to report back to the monitor, as well as how do I keep track of all the threads? Right now I start them, and stack them in an ArrayList, but that is (to my knowledge) not automatically updated, which means it should be updated after the thread is done? I have done the first sorting, read from and to file.